# JHipster Persist Data/Access Database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jhipster

Running with Spring Boot v1.1.7.RELEASE, Spring v4.0.7.RELEASE with hot reloading, etc.

Hey JHipsters,
I'm working on my first project with JHipster. I can successfully create an application that runs, authenticates, etc. My issues really began when I started to try to create and maintain entities. At this point I've created an entity successfully called "Employees" with all the supporting files that JHipster provides. I've also managed to add the fields that I wanted to that entity (which proved to be more difficult than I originally anticipated), but wasn't able to eliminate the sample fields without creating an error, so I've left them there.

Now, maybe I'm missing something here, but when I go and save a group of values in my entity, as soon as I terminate my application, those values evaporate. Is JHipster designed to operate this way in developer mode? If so, how do I persist my values in the MYSQL database that JHipster created for me?

Let me know if you need any more information from me to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a chance that in your `yo jhipster` command, you chose in the question for database development, the option H2 memory ?

This way, it's normal that you lost your data.
May be you can change this option to use a real Database.

Comment: Mmm, that makes sense. I'll try making another website that doesn't use H2 and mark this as correct if that's the issue.

Comment: Yes it's designed to work this way, if of course you selected "h2 in memory" during generation. That's why it's called "in memory". If you don't like this behavior (depends on your taste, really), use a "real" database instead.

Comment: It's definitely useful for development. I was concerned for when I would eventually be using MySQL for production  as I was getting the error seen in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219052/jhipster-persist-data-access-database) when I tried to run the production environment. Thanks for helping me figure out where I was misunderstanding guys.